# Moving ipad pictures to a different computer

Tags: itunes, ipad, photos

I previously have synced an old ipad with my computer. Then I gave my ipad to my dad to use.

Now, it appears, that ipad somehow keeps track of the pictures I sync'ed with my computer differently from the pictures my dad has currently taken. For example, when I open up this ipad on my dad's computer, the bottom of the iTunes shows 5G of "pictures", and 17.20G of "others", presumably the materials sync'ed with my old computer.

If I check the "Storage" of the ipad, it lists a few items, and one item being "synchronized from itunes".

if I click on "Pictures" tab, and I check "sync pictures", the itunes popup says something like "this ipad is already synchronized with another itunes database on "[MY OLD PC]". do you want to wipe out and sync the ipad with this itunes?"

I don't want to do that. I want to sync the entire ipad to my dad's computer, including the pictures I have taken before giving the ipad to my dad.

I frankly don't remember which computer I used to sync with this ipad long ago. I guess my question is, how do I sync ALL pictures on this ipad to a brand new computer?

Answer (score 1):

If you erased the iPad before giving it to your dad, then this issue wouldn't have happened.

Anyways, can you view the iPad like a camera (in windows explorer)? Then can you copy all of the pictures off?

The warning from iTunes about erasing doesn't always mean it *will* erase the iPad; I've had to sync my device to a new iTunes and It didn't actually erase (but your experience may vary)